# apollo recieved array data repeat last record

Tags: graphql, apollo

Fetching data from graphql - express server and it contains

```js
course
:
["MAT", "FEN", "SOSYAL"]
list
:
[{_id: {totGrade: 11, totLetter: "B", __typename: "StudentNumbersSub"}, countx: 1,…},…]
0
:
{_id: {totGrade: 11, totLetter: "B", __typename: "StudentNumbersSub"}, countx: 1,…}
1
:
{_id: {totGrade: 10, totLetter: "C", __typename: "StudentNumbersSub"}, countx: 1,…}
2
:
{_id: {totGrade: 9, totLetter: "B", __typename: "StudentNumbersSub"}, countx: 3,…}
3
:
{_id: {totGrade: 10, totLetter: "B", __typename: "StudentNumbersSub"}, countx: 2,…}
4
:
{_id: {totGrade: 9, totLetter: "A", __typename: "StudentNumbersSub"}, countx: 2,…}
```

so correct data coming but after subscription it from apollo object

```js
  this.dataPeriodService.serverQueryData.subscribe(({data}) => {
    console.log ('received data:', data);
    }
```

the data object only repeat  last record as array lenght count in this example

{_id: {totGrade: 9, totLetter: "A", __typename: "StudentNumbersSub"}, countx: 2,…}

so it only contains this record

how can fix that?

thanks everone!

Comment: Can be mapping bug about Apollo ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it adding alias the _id field but seem not reliable